# SSLServerSocket throwing EOFException

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, serversocket

I'm currently trying to implement SSL connections in my program. But when I now try to launch it, a NoSuchAlgorithmException is thrown on top of the stack trace.

Here's the complete stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.throwException(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:159)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:171)
    at net.dreamcode.im.server.IMServer.startServer(IMServer.java:155)
    at net.dreamcode.im.server.IMServer.main(IMServer.java:66)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1262)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:97)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:113)
    at net.dreamcode.im.server.IMServer.startServer(IMServer.java:153)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:645)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultKeyManager(SSLContextImpl.java:610)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:495)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1238)
    ... 7 more
```

So, if we look into it, we see this EOFException - the meaning of this is clear. If I open the keystore file, it is empty. But I just don't know why.
Here's how I try to generate the keystore and certificate:

```
Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("**** IMPORTANT ****");
System.out.println("You don't have a certificate for using SSL yet.");
System.out.println("We will create it together now!");
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Name of your organisation: ");
String ssl_o = scr.nextLine();
String ssl_ou = ssl_o;
System.out.print("Your name: ");
String ssl_cn = scr.nextLine();
System.out.print("Country code [de/en/fr]: ");
String ssl_c = scr.nextLine();
System.out.print("City: ");
String ssl_l = scr.nextLine();
System.out.print("State: ");
String ssl_st = scr.nextLine();
System.out.print("Password: ");
String pass = new String(scr.nextLine());

String execString = "keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias dreamim -keystore " + KEYSTORE + " -storepass " + pass + " -validity 360 -dname \"cn=" + ssl_cn + ", o=" + ssl_o + ", ou=" + ssl_ou + ", c=" + ssl_c + ", l=" + ssl_l + ", st=" + ssl_st + "\" -keypass " + pass;
try
{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execString);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, when trying to create the SSLServerSocket, I simply use this:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(port);
```

I don't execute the JAR file by passing the key store argument but I'm using this code before creating the socket:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", KEYSTORE);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't going to work anyway. The client is not going to trust a newly created certificate, unless you've broken its SSL by allowing it to trust any certificate. However you could try testing the return code of the exec'd process instead of just assuming it worked.

Comment: @EJP I'm aware of that. I would add this certificate to the trust store of the specific client. I will check the return code thingy, good idea.